# How to hide a menu when clicked on any menu-item?

Tags: javascript

I can not find where is the problem. Any idea about hiding  on clicking any menu-item?

```js
var button = document.getElementById("#1");
var menu = document.getElementById("#menu");
button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (menu.style.display == "block") {
    menu.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    menu.style.display == "block";
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#home" id="1" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#model-s" id="1" class="one">Model S</a></li>
  <li><a href="#model3" id="1">Model 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#modelx" id="1">Model X</a></li>
  <li><a href="#modely" id="1">Model Y</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This error means that "button" doesn't exist. That's because you incorrectly used getElementById. Check [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to see how it was applied correctly. Apart from that there shouldn't be more than one identical id.

Comment: FYI there are a ton of [other reasons](/q/14028959) why getElementById might fail. Most important is to run it only after the DOM exists, meaning classically running the js <script> at the end of the <body>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot get `document.getElementById("#1")` with `#`. `getElementById` is already an id selector, so you don't need to have `#`.

`menu.style.display`, you don't have inline styles for `menu`, your condition won't pass for the first time.

You also cannot have multiple `id` in your elements because `id` should be unique. In that case, you should use class instead (I added `menu-item` classes for element selectors)

I've tried to change your code with some comments

```js
//get all menu items
var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item");
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
for (const menuItem of menuItems) {
  //add click events to menu items
  menuItem.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    //hide menu if click on menu item
    menu.style.display = "none";
  });
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#home" class="active menu-item">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#model-s" class="one menu-item">Model S</a></li>
  <li><a href="#model3" class="menu-item">Model 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#modelx" class="menu-item">Model X</a></li>
  <li><a href="#modely" class="menu-item">Model Y</a></li>
</ul>
```